# The middos tag: God's or ours?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I recently saw [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13889/759) marked [middos-character-traits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middos-character-traits). I removed the tag. The [only other question I can find](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7783/759) regarding the God's 13 middot of mercy was only tagged [selichot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selichot). I think [middos-character-traits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middos-character-traits) should be for questions regarding human character traits. Any question regarding God's 13 middot that I can imagine will fit into [selichot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selichot) or possible [tefilla](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilla). What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

That question was about saying the 13 *midos*, which I agree should not be tagged with the [middos-character-traits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middos-character-traits) tag, though it could be tagged with the (currently nonexistent) [13-midos-of-hashem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/13-midos-of-hashem) tag. However, a question about *erech apayim* or one of the other *midos* of *Hashem* could IMO be tagged with the former as long as we don't have the latter.